# creating svg documents using visual c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, svg

Does anyone has created SVG docs using Visual C++? I am looking for some basic tutorials and my googling seem to fail me. I am not sure if its possible at all to create a SVG doc programatically. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: SVG is just XML as I know. If you can create XML using C++ then you can create SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [CairoGraphics](http://cairographics.org/) it is a C library which can create and edit SVG files.